# PHP scripts run only in webroot directory,and return 500 error in other dirs

Tags: php, directory

I have uploaded a folder with php scripts and they run only when they are in the webroot directory,Everytime i try to execute php script in some internal dir,i get internal server error,even if it works in the parent directory

EDIT:So,i it's apache 2 server,nothing is logged in my error log about the errors in the internal directory ,
permissions for php file and for the direcory  are

```
-rw-r--r--    drwxrwxr-x
```

Comment: We need more information. Which Webserver are you using. What gets logged in your webserver's error log when this happens. We could also do with seeing the relevant parts of your webserver config.

Comment: File permissions would be nice as well.

Comment: ok ..............................

Answer (score 0):

Check your vhosts apache confs (if you're using apache) and .htaccess file in the internal directory (may be some syntax error in those .htaccess)